# Node.js: How to handle request object in domain module on error event

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some http-server which is wrapped by domain-module.
Server send error on some request. Is there any approach to get request object which provoked error?

```
var http = require('http');
var domain = require('domain');
var d = domain.create();
d.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error("Sorry, dude, we have a problem");
    console.error(err.stack);
});
d.run(function() {
        http.createServer(function(req, res) {
            someBadFunction();
            res.end();
        }).listen(8080);
    }
);
```

Comment: Are you saying if an exception is thrown inside the `createServer` callback your domain doesn't catch the error? There really isn't a lot of information to go on here....

Comment: @James, Domain catchs errors, everything works correct, but I need to know request parameters for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the request to the domain, and filter it out in the error handler:

```
d.on('error', function(err) {
  var req = d.members.filter(function(member) {
    return member instanceof http.IncomingMessage;
  })[0];
  d.remove(req);
  ...
});

d.run(function() {
  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    d.add(req);
    someBadFunction();
    res.end();
  }).listen(8080);
});
```

However, if I were to use domains (they are being deprecated), I would create a new domain for each request (as per [this documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_explicit_binding)) instead of adding each request to the top-level domain, as I don't think the code above will work properly with any reasonable amount of requests coming in.

Comment: Thanks, @robertklep, it is exactly what I wanted.